# Changing postgresql 9.3 database location on Amazon ec2 linux

Tags: postgresql, amazon-ec2, postgresql-9.3

I apologize for the long post. I have a Postgresql 9.3 server running on a Amazon linux AMI. I also have a compressed dump file from another server which I created using pg_dumpall. Now, I want to restore the data from this dump file in my Postgres. However, I want to load this data into a specific location (say /data).

I'm having a fresh installation of Postgres. So when I tried to do a:

```
sudo service postgresql93 start
```

I got an error message asking me to initialize the db. So I did a:

```
sudo service postgresql initdb
```

which created the required files in `/var/lib/pgsql93/data`. After that, I changed the 'data_directory' configuration in `/var/lib/pgsql93/data/postgresql.conf` and pointed it to /data (I had to do this as root user. I couldn't open the file as the default user).

Now when I try to do a

```
sudo service postgresql93 start
```

it fails to start, and when I check the /var/lib/pgsql93/pg_startup.log file, it says:

```
FATAL:  "/data/postgresql" is not a valid data directory
DETAIL:  File "/data/postgresql/PG_VERSION" is missing.
```

So I copied the files from the default (/var/lib/pgsql9.3/data) to /data, changed the permissions to 700 and owner to postgres.

However, when I try to start the service again, it still fails, and in the pgstartup.log, it only says:

```
LOG:  redirecting log output to logging collector process
HINT:  Future log output will appear in directory "pg_log".
```

And when I check the log in /data/pg_log, it says:

```
LOG:  database system was shut down at 2014-12-30 21:31:18 UTC
LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
LOG:  autovacuum launcher started
```

What else could be the problem? I haven't restored the data yet. I just have the files which were created by the initdb command.

Comment: You should probably run your initdb after you change the config file.

Comment: http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-server-73/change-postgresql-data-directory-649911/

Comment: I know this is not part of what you're asking, but have you considered using RDS. It makes tasks like this much easier.

Comment: @drunkenfist, glad to hear that. Maybe you can make a conclusion  to answer your own question.

Answer (score 0):

@BMW http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-server-73/change-postgresql-data-directory-649911/ is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks.